# Magento2: Invalidate Particular Product Page Cache From Observer

Tags: magento2, event-observer, full-page-cache

Hi I have a Observer written on save before event on catalog my events.xml is

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="catalog_product_save_after">
        <observer name="mynamespace_mymodule_observer" instance="MyNameSpace\Mymodule\Model\Observer"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

What i want is to invalidate this product page cache if Data is changed

```
 public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer ){}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll be surprised, but magento 2 performs "cache invalidation" after product save. Let's take a look in `module-page-cache/etc/events.xml` where we find `controller_action_postdispatch_catalog_product_save` as listened event.

```
   <event name="controller_action_postdispatch_catalog_product_save">
    <observer name="flush_all_pagecache" instance="Magento\PageCache\Observer\FlushCacheByTags" />
   </event>
```

Next, in class `Magento\PageCache\Observer\FlushCacheByTags`, built-In cache is cleaned considering the tags of incoming object, in method `execute()`

```
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        if ($this->_config->getType() == \Magento\PageCache\Model\Config::BUILT_IN && $this->_config->isEnabled()) {
            $object = $observer->getEvent()->getObject();
            if (!is_object($object)) {
                return;
            }
            $tags = $this->getTagResolver()->getTags($object);

            if (!empty($tags)) {
                $this->getCache()->clean(\Zend_Cache::CLEANING_MODE_MATCHING_ANY_TAG, array_unique($tags));
            }
        }
    }
```